# Freebase combined query empty result set

Tags: freebase, mql

I am trying to query freebase to get all the award winning movies that a person directed or acted in. If I run this with Steven Spielberg (who has both directed AND acted in award winning movies), it works fine:

```
[{
  "/type/object/mid": "/m/06pj8",
  "/film/director/film": [{
    "type": "/award/award_winning_work",
    "name": null
  }],
  "/film/actor/film": [{
    "film": [{
      "type": "/award/award_winning_work",
      "name": null
    }]
  }]
}]
```

But the same query with Matt Damon (/m/0169dl) (who has not directed award winning movies but acts in those movies) returns nothing. I would expect to return all the movies Matt Damon acted in, in this case.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in a single query without a little bit of post-processing, but adding `optional:true` to the subqueries will get you close

```
[{
  "/type/object/mid": "/m/06pj8",
  "/film/director/film": [{
    "type": "/award/award_winning_work",
    "name": null,
    "optional": true
  }],
  "/film/actor/film": [{
    "film": [{
      "type": "/award/award_winning_work",
      "name": null,
      "optional": true
    }]
  }]
}]
```

Comment: brilliant! exactly what I was looking for. just wondering if you know why it does not return anything by default? is that the expected behavior?

Comment: The default is equivalent to optional:false and all filters are ANDed together, so any topics which don't  match both subqueries by having award winning works will fail to meet the criteria.